# Can "sequentially" be used to describe the order of arrangement?

Tags: adverbs

I am trying to describe the situation shown in the image as simply as possible.[image]

My example is as follows:

> A,B, and C are sequentially arranged from the wall.

Could you advise me on whether the word "sequentially" involves the positional order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is technically correct, but most people wouldn't use it that way. In my experience, people use "sequentially" to refer to sequences of numbers or steps in a list or procedure. 
I would probably go with something like, "A, B, and C are arranged alphabetically, moving away from the wall."

Comment: "A, B, C" are just example names, so I would like to know how to describe the situation without "alphabetically".